# Dual of the fractional Sobolev space $W^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, fourier-analysis, dual-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

For $s\in\mathbb{R}$ and $1<p<\infty$, one can define the fractional Sobolev space $W^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Every element $f$ in $W^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is a tempered distribution such that the inverse Fourier transform of 
$$\widehat{f_s}(\xi):=(1+|\xi|^2)^{\frac{s}{2}}\hat{f}(\xi)$$ 
is an element of $L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and we define 
$$\|f\|_{W^{s,p}}:=\|f_s\|_{L^p}.$$ 
Note that the function $(1+|\xi|^2)^{\frac{s}{2}}$ has at most polynomial order growth, thus $(1+|\xi|^2)^{\frac{s}{2}}\hat{f}(\xi)$ is in fact a well defined tempered distribution and so is its inverse Fourier transform. I'm looking for refrences which deal with the dual space of $W^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. I have seen huge literatures on the case $p=2$, in which case the space $W^{s,2}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a Hilbert space with inner product
$$\langle f,g\rangle_{W^{s,2}}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\hat{f}(\xi)\overline{\hat{g}(\xi)}(1+|\xi|^2)^sd\xi.$$
And the dual space of $W^{s,2}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is precisely $W^{-s,2}(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

Unlike the case $p=2$, I didn't find any resources which discuss the duality when $p\neq 2$. I've seen some resources mentioned that the dual of $W^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is $W^{-s,q}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, where $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. Intuitively this makes sense from the duality of $L^p$ spaces. But I didn't see any proof of this.

Could someone provide me some references related to this quesiton? Or maybe explain to me in details if applicable? Thanks in advance!

P.S. I saw some resources which define the Sobolev spaces of negative powers to be the dual of Soboleve spaces of positive powers, i.e., they define
$$W^{-s,q}(\mathbb{R}^n):=(W^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n))'$$
when $s>0$ and $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. I would like to see whether this coincides with the definition I provided above.

Comment: My go-to reference for such results is Triebel, Theory of function spaces, tomes I, II or III. Not having the books with me, I can't point to a precise result, but I think the answer to this question should be in the first book.

Answer (score 3):

So a good reference for that are the books *Theory of function spaces I* and *II* by H. Triebel.

In particular, the space that you define here is the space $F^s_{p,2}$ (see for example the last Theorem in section 1.5.1 in *Theory of function spaces II*) often denoted as $H^{s,p}$ and called the Bessel-Sobolev space which can be seen as complex interpolation of Sobolev spaces (see also [Is $B^s_{p,p} = W^{s,p}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3709099/is-bs-p-p-ws-p/3709151#3709151)), or also defined with a Littlewood-Paley decomposition. And you can find the fact that $(F^s_{p,q})' = F^{-s}_{p',q'}$ in *Theory of function spaces II*, section 2.11.2 (and it is also indicated in *Theory of function spaces II*, section 1.5.2)